# How do I create an average from a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would get find an average from an array?

If I have the array:

```
[0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
```

Averaging would give me 3.375.

Comment: If you're getting 21.75 as the average of those numbers, something's very wrong...

Comment: dotty, not sure how you got 21.75 but the average/mean for that set of data is 3.375 and the sum is 27. i'm not sure what sort of aggregation function would yield 21.75. Please double check and make sure that average is really what you're after!

Comment: I have NO idea where i got 21.75 from.

Must had press something like 0+48+2+5+0+2+6 on the calculator!

Comment: Since this is also tagged ruby-on-rails, active record calculations are worth looking into if you are averaging an ActiveRecord array.

Person.average(:age, :country => 'Brazil') 

returns the average age of people from Brazil.  Pretty cool!

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [5, 6, 7, 8]
arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
=> 6.5
```

Note the `.to_f`, which you'll want for avoiding any problems from integer division. You can also do:

```
arr = [5, 6, 7, 8]
arr.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el } / arr.size
=> 6.5
```

You can define it as part of `Array` as another commenter has suggested, but you need to avoid integer division or your results will be wrong. Also, this isn't generally applicable to every possible element type (obviously, an average only makes sense for things that can be averaged). But if you want to go that route, use this:

```
class Array
  def sum
    inject(0.0) { |result, el| result + el }
  end

  def mean 
    sum / size
  end
end
```

If you haven't seen `inject` before, it's not as magical as it might appear. It iterates over each element and then applies an accumulator value to it. The accumulator is then handed to the next element. In this case, our accumulator is simply an integer that reflects the sum of all the previous elements.

**Edit:** Commenter Dave Ray proposed a nice improvement.

**Edit:** Commenter Glenn Jackman's proposal, using `arr.inject(:+).to_f`, is nice too but perhaps a bit too clever if you don't know what's going on. The `:+` is a symbol; when passed to inject, it applies the method named by the symbol (in this case, the addition operation) to each element against the accumulator value.

Comment: You can eliminate to_f and ? operator by passing an initial value to inject: `arr.inject(0.0) { |sum,el| sum + el } / arr.size`.

Comment: Or: arr.inject(:+).to_f / arr.size # => 3.375

Comment: @glenn: That's nice too, but I think the Symbol#to_proc automatic conversion is just a bit too clever for a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I don't think this warrants adding to the Array class, since it's not generalizable to all the types that Arrays can contain.

Comment: @John: That's not exactly Symbol#to_proc conversion — it's part of the `inject` interface, mentioned in the documentation. The `to_proc` operator is `&`.

Comment: The more I see inject, the less I like it :P

Comment: `arr.inject(:+).to_f/arr.length`

Comment: If you're using Rails, `Array#inject` is overkill here. Just use `#sum`. E.g. `arr.sum.to_f / arr.size`

Comment: This answer should be updated to include (and probably prefer) `arr.sum` instead of `arr.reduce(:+)`.

Comment: is there a way to do this so that it is chainable, like `map` is? (or is it chainable and I just don't know it?

Answer (score 123):

```
a = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
a.instance_eval { reduce(:+) / size.to_f } #=> 3.375
```

A version of this that does not use `instance_eval` would be:

```
a = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
a.reduce(:+) / a.size.to_f #=> 3.375
```

Comment: Hi, Corban. I'm looking for some documentation on ":+".  Does that fit into a "class" of symbols that a function, like reduce, can use?  Thank you.

Comment: This one could be considered too clever, but very useful when you're inside of the console session and don't want to be extending Array class or storing Array in separate variable, so +1 definitely!

Comment: I don't think it is too clever. I think it solves the problem idiomatically. I.e., it uses reduce, which is exactly correct. Programmers should be encouraged to understand what is correct, why it is correct, and then propagate. For a trivial operation like average, true, one doesn't need to be "clever". But by understanding what "reduce" is for a trivial case, one can then start applying it to much more complex problems. upvote.

Comment: why the need for instance_eval here?

Comment: `instance_eval` lets you run the code while only specifying `a` once, so it can be chained with other commands. I.e. `random_average = Array.new(10) { rand(10) }.instance_eval { reduce(:+) / size.to_f } ` instead of `random = Array.new(10) { rand(10) }; random_average = random.reduce(:+) / random.size`

Comment: I don't know, using instance_eval this way just seems weird, and it has a lot of gotchas associated with it that make this approach a bad idea, IMO. (For example, if you tried to access and instance variable or a method on `self` inside that block, you'd run into problems.) `instance_eval` is more for metaprogramming or DSL.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I agree, don't use this in your application code. It was however very nice to be able to paste into my repl (:

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for! This is a _perfect_ appropriate use of `instance_eval`. I do not understand the nay-sayers. If you already have your array in a variable, then sure, `a.reduce(:+) / a.size.to_f ` is pretty reasonable. But if you want to  "in line" find the mean of an array _literal_ or an array that is returned from a function/expression — without duplicating the entire expression (`[0,4,8].reduce(:+) / [0,4,8].length.to_f`, for example, is abhorrent) or being _required_ to assign to a local, then `instance_eval` option is a beautiful, elegant, idiomatic solution!!

Comment: `instance_eval` is analogous to using `tap`, `yield_self`, … when you are dealing with a chain of method calls: _do use it_ whenever it's appropriate and helpful! And in this case, I absolutely believe that it is.

Comment: Or if you're looking for a core extension that adds this to the `Array` class, I'd recommend the facets gem (`require 'facets/array/average'`). Then you can just do `array.average`. And, from looking at the source, it turns out they do the _exact_ same thing as the `instance_eval` approach above. The only difference is that it's implemented as a method—which of course _already_ has `self` pointing to itself—instead of a block):
```def average;  return nil if empty?; reduce(:+) / length.to_f; end```
Main advantage of this is that it's even more concise/readable and it handles the empty? case.

Answer (score 96):

I believe the simplest answer is

```
list.reduce(:+).to_f / list.size
```

Comment: It took me a moment to find it -- `reduce` is a method of the `Enumerable` mixin used by `Array`.  And despite its name, I agree with the @ShuWu ... unless you're using Rails which implements `sum`.

Comment: I see solutions here, that I know that look extremely neat, but I'm afraid if I read my code in the future they'll like gibberish. Thanks for the clean solution!

Comment: On my system this is 3x faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 58):

I was hoping for Math.average(values), but no such luck.

```
values = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
average = values.sum / values.size.to_f
```

Comment: I didn't realize #sum was added by Rails! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: After Christmas 2016 (Ruby 2.4), Array _will_ have a `sum` method, so this appears to be a correct answer after 6 years,  worthy of the Nostradamus award.

Answer (score 57):

Ruby versions >= 2.4 has an [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method.

And to get floating point average, you can use [Integer#fdiv](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv)

```
arr = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]

arr.sum.fdiv(arr.size)
# => 3.375
```

For older versions:

```
arr.reduce(:+).fdiv(arr.size)
# => 3.375
```

Answer (score 16):

Without having to repeat the array (e.g. perfect for one-liners):

```rb
[1, 2, 3, 4].then { |a| a.sum.to_f / a.size }
```

With block arguments:

```rb
[1, 2, 3, 4].then { _1.sum.to_f / _1.size }
```

With Ruby 3.4 it keyword:

```rb
[1, 2, 3, 4].then { it.sum.to_f / it.size }
```

Comment: I loved the `.then`!

Answer (score 13):

Some benchmarking of top solutions (in order of most efficient):

#### Large Array:

```
array = (1..10_000_000).to_a

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report { array.instance_eval { reduce(:+) / size.to_f } }
  bm.report { array.sum.fdiv(array.size) }
  bm.report { array.sum / array.size.to_f }
  bm.report { array.reduce(:+).to_f / array.size }
  bm.report { array.reduce(:+).try(:to_f).try(:/, array.size) }
  bm.report { array.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / array.size }
  bm.report { array.reduce([ 0.0, 0 ]) { |(s, c), e| [ s + e, c + 1 ] }.reduce(:/) }
end


    user     system      total        real
0.480000   0.000000   0.480000   (0.473920)
0.500000   0.000000   0.500000   (0.502158)
0.500000   0.000000   0.500000   (0.508075)
0.510000   0.000000   0.510000   (0.512600)
0.520000   0.000000   0.520000   (0.516096)
0.760000   0.000000   0.760000   (0.767743)
1.530000   0.000000   1.530000   (1.534404)
```

#### Small Arrays:

```
array = Array.new(10) { rand(0.5..2.0) }

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.reduce(:+).to_f / array.size } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.sum / array.size.to_f } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.sum.fdiv(array.size) } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.inject(0.0) { |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / array.size } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.instance_eval { reduce(:+) / size.to_f } } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.reduce(:+).try(:to_f).try(:/, array.size) } }
  bm.report { 1_000_000.times { array.reduce([ 0.0, 0 ]) { |(s, c), e| [ s + e, c + 1 ] }.reduce(:/) } }
end


    user     system      total        real
0.760000   0.000000   0.760000   (0.760353)
0.870000   0.000000   0.870000   (0.876087)
0.900000   0.000000   0.900000   (0.901102)
0.920000   0.000000   0.920000   (0.920888)
0.950000   0.000000   0.950000   (0.952842)
1.690000   0.000000   1.690000   (1.694117)
1.840000   0.010000   1.850000   (1.845623)
```

Comment: Your benchmark is a bit wrong. benchmark/ips is actually better for these kind of comparisons. Also I would suggest to use an Array populated randomly with negative and positive numbers as well as floats, to get a more realistic result. You'll find that instance_eval is slower than array.sum.fdiv . By about 8x for floats. and about x1.12 for integers. Also, different OSes will give different results.  on my mac some of these methods are 2 times as slow than on my Linux Droplet

Comment: Also sum method uses Gauss's formula, on ranges instead of calculating the sum.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Array
  def sum 
    inject( nil ) { |sum,x| sum ? sum+x : x }
  end

  def mean 
    sum.to_f / size.to_f
  end
end

[0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6].mean
```

Comment: This returns incorrect values because of integer division. Try it with, for example, [2,3].mean, which returns 2 instead of 2.5.

Comment: Why should an empty array have a sum of `nil` rather than 0?

Comment: Because you can get the difference between [] and [0]. And I think everybody who want a real mean can make use of to_i or replace the above nil with an 0

Answer (score 4):

Let me bring something into competition which solves the division by zero problem:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.reduce(:+).try(:to_f).try(:/,a.size) #==> 4.5

a = []
a.reduce(:+).try(:to_f).try(:/,a.size) #==> nil
```

I must admit, however, that "try" is a Rails helper. But you can easily solve this:

```
class Object;def try(*options);self&&send(*options);end;end
class Array;def avg;reduce(:+).try(:to_f).try(:/,size);end;end
```

BTW: I think it is correct that the average of an empty list is nil. The average of nothing is nothing, not 0. So that is expected behavior. However, if you change to:

```
class Array;def avg;reduce(0.0,:+).try(:/,size);end;end
```

the result for empty Arrays won't be an exception as I had expected but instead it returns NaN... I've never seen that before in Ruby. ;-) Seems to be a special behavior of the Float class...

```
0.0/0 #==> NaN
0.1/0 #==> Infinity
0.0.class #==> Float
```

Answer (score 3):

what I don't like about the accepted solution

```
arr = [5, 6, 7, 8]
arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
=> 6.5
```

is that it does not really work in a purely functional way.
we need a variable arr to compute arr.size at the end.

to solve this purely functionally we need to keep track of two
values: the sum of all elements, and the number of elements.

```
[5, 6, 7, 8].inject([0.0,0]) do |r,ele|
    [ r[0]+ele, r[1]+1 ]
end.inject(:/)
=> 6.5
```

Santhosh improved on this solution: instead of the argument r being an array, we could use destructuring to immediatly pick it apart into two variables

```
[5, 6, 7, 8].inject([0.0,0]) do |(sum, size), ele| 
   [ sum + ele, size + 1 ]
end.inject(:/)
```

if you want to see how it works, add some puts:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8].inject([0.0,0]) do |(sum, size), ele| 
   r2 = [ sum + ele, size + 1 ]
   puts "adding #{ele} gives #{r2}"
   r2
end.inject(:/)

adding 5 gives [5.0, 1]
adding 6 gives [11.0, 2]
adding 7 gives [18.0, 3]
adding 8 gives [26.0, 4]
=> 6.5
```

We could also use a struct instead of an array to contain the sum and the count, but then we have to declare the struct first:

```
R=Struct.new(:sum, :count)
[5, 6, 7, 8].inject( R.new(0.0, 0) ) do |r,ele|
    r.sum += ele
    r.count += 1
    r
end.inject(:/)
```

Comment: This is the first time I see `end.method` used in ruby, thanks for this!

Comment: The array passed to inject method can be dispersed. `arr.inject([0.0,0]) { |(sum, size), el| [ sum + el, size + 1 ] }.inject(:/)`

Comment: @Santhosh: yes, that's a lot more readable!  I would not call this "dispersing" though, I would call it "destructuring" http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html

Answer (score 3):

For public amusement, yet another solution:

```
a = 0, 4, 8, 2, 5, 0, 2, 6
a.reduce [ 0.0, 0 ] do |(s, c), e| [ s + e, c + 1 ] end.reduce :/
#=> 3.375
```

Comment: If this was higher up in the voting I would not have understood it! Very good.

Comment: _Clear is better than clever_, this piece of code isn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution too

```
arr = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
arr.sum(0.0) / arr.size
```

Answer (score 3):

You can choose one of the below solutions as you wish.

### Bruteforce

```rb
[0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6].sum.to_f / [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6].size.to_f

=> 3.375
```

### Method

```rb
def avg(array)
  array.sum.to_f / array.size.to_f
end  

avg([0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6])
=> 3.375
```

### Monkey Patching

```rb
class Array
  def avg
    sum.to_f / size.to_f
  end
end

[0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6].avg
=> 3.375
```

But I don't recommend to monkey patch the Array class, this practice is dangerous and can potentially lead to undesirable effects on your system.

For our good, ruby language provides a nice feature to overcome this problem, the Refinements, which is a safe way for monkey patching on ruby.

To simplify, with the [Refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) you can monkey patch the `Array` class and the changes will only be available inside the scope of the class that is using the refinement! :)

You can use the refinement inside the class you are working on and you are ready to go.

#### Refinements

```rb
module ArrayRefinements
  refine Array do
    def avg
      sum.to_f / size.to_f
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  using ArrayRefinements

  def test(array)
    array.avg
  end
end

MyClass.new.test([0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6])
=> 3.375
```

Comment: Another option: `[0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6].then { |a| a.sum.to_f / a.size.to_f }`

Answer (score 2):

Don't have ruby on this pc, but something to this extent should work:

```
values = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
total = 0.0
values.each do |val|
 total += val
end

average = total/values.size
```

Answer (score 2):

### Add `Array#average`.

I was doing the same thing quite often so I thought it was prudent to just extend the `Array` class with a simple `average` method. It doesn't work for anything besides an Array of numbers like Integers or Floats or Decimals but it's handy when you use it right.

I'm using Ruby on Rails so I've placed this in `config/initializers/array.rb` but you can place it anywhere that's included on boot, etc.

**`config/initializers/array.rb`**

```
class Array

  # Will only work for an Array of numbers like Integers, Floats or Decimals.
  #
  # Throws various errors when trying to call it on an Array of other types, like Strings.
  # Returns nil for an empty Array.
  #
  def average
    return nil if self.empty?

    self.sum.to_d / self.size
  end

end
```

Comment: Does not work if the average is a decimal value. For example: `[1, 2, 3, 4].average`. It is returning `2` instead of `2.5`. If somebody desires a fully working solution with Monkey Patch, it can be found 
right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65337711/7644846

Comment: @Victor You're right! Thanks for the heads up. Seems like a pretty obvious omission on my part. I fixed it by converting the `sum` to a `BigDecimal` before dividing by the `size`. Now, `[1, 2, 3, 4].average #=> 0.25e1`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
sum = 0
a.each { |b| sum += b }
average = sum / a.length
```

Comment: This will return incorrect values because of integer division. For example, if a is [2, 3], the expected result is 2.5, but you'll return 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
a.empty? ? nil : a.reduce(:+)/a.size.to_f
=> 3.375
```

Solves divide by zero, integer division and is easy to read. Can be easily modified if you choose to have an empty array return 0.

I like this variant too, but it's a little more wordy.

```
a = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
a.empty? ? nil : [a.reduce(:+), a.size.to_f].reduce(:/)
=> 3.375
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6]
average = arr.inject(&:+).to_f / arr.size
# => 3.375
```

Answer (score 1):

This method can be helpful.

```
def avg(arr)
  val = 0.0

  arr.each do |n|
    val += n
  end

  len = arr.length

  val / len 
end

p avg([0,4,8,2,5,0,2,6])
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow here Original Poster of the question wants the answer as 3.375 and your solution gives 3. i,e 27 / 8 = 3.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I know the Original Poster of the question wants answer as 3.375 and thats what this method does as I have given variable 'var' a float value (i.e; 0.0). Munim Munna I have to agree with u there is indeed a similar ans.

Answer (score 0):

print array.sum / array.count is how i've done it

Answer (score 0):

I really like to define a `mean()` method so my code is more expressive.

I usually want to ignore `nil` by default, so here's what I define

```rb
def mean(arr)
  arr.compact.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.compact.size
end

mean([1, nil, 5])
=> 3.0
```

If you want to keep the `nil`s, just remove *both* the `.compact`s.

Answer (score 0):

A much faster solution than .inject is :

> arr.sum(0.0) / arr.size

See this article for ref: https://andycroll.com/ruby/calculate-a-mean-average-from-a-ruby-array/

Answer (score -1):

```
[1,2].tap { |a| @asize = a.size }.inject(:+).to_f/@asize
```

Short but using instance variable

Comment: I'd do `a_size = nil; [1,2].tap { |a| a_size = a.size }.inject(:+).to_f/a_size` rather than create an instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
(a.sum/a.length).to_f
# => 3.0
```

Comment: Does not work when the average should be a decimal value. Test this code with this array: `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. The average should be `2.5` instead of `2.0`. It should be `a.sum.to_f / a.length.to_f` instead.