# Hash/Ruby - Select last 4 values (to average) in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash, that I select all the data for a dashboard to display performance, since displaying the latest value isn't always helpful, I'm trying to select the last 4 values from a hash.

I have attempted the `thing.last(4)`, but to no avail.

Code is below, essentially trying to display the last 4 from `top_points`, or average points.

Note: Ruby 1.9

```
metric.sort.each do |key, value|
  top_point = { x: Time.parse(key).to_time.to_i, y: value['top_10'] }
  top_points << top_point

  average_point = { x: Time.parse(key).to_time.to_i, y: value['average'] }
  average_points << average_point
end
```

Comment: `thing.values[-4..-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in order to get the last four elements of your hash, you should first `map` it as an array, get the indexes desired and then transform again the array into an hash.

For example:

```
2.2.1 :001 > hash = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
 => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5} 
2.2.1 :002 > hash.map{|h| h}[-4..-1].to_h
 => {:b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5}
```

In your specific case, the code might look like this:

```
metric.sort.map{|h| h}[-4..-1].to_h.each do |key, value|
    top_point = { x: Time.parse(key).to_time.to_i, y: value['top_10'] }
    top_points << top_point

    average_point = { x: Time.parse(key).to_time.to_i, y: value['average'] }
    average_points << average_point
  end
```

Another way to write it could be:

```
last_four_metrics = metric.sort.map{|h| h}[-4..-1].to_h
top_points = last_four_metrics.map{|k, v| { x: Time.parse(k).to_time.to_i, y: v['top_10'] }}
average_points = last_four_metrics.map{|k, v| { x: Time.parse(k).to_time.to_i, y: v['average'] }}
```

Update: compatibility with Ruby 1.9

```
last_four_metrics = Hash[ metric.sort.map{|h| h}[-4..-1] ]

top_points = last_four_metrics.map{|k, v| { x: Time.parse(k).to_time.to_i, y: v['top_10'] }}
average_points = last_four_metrics.map{|k, v| { x: Time.parse(k).to_time.to_i, y: v['average'] }}
```

Comment: I sort of like this best. I would although have it sepereated since what I'm doing is the graph will display as is, but the "key" or "legend" would say the averages. Ran into this when trying to implement to_h NoMethodError
  70214561670280     undefined method `to_h' for #<Array:0x007fb834034a28>
 I am using 1.9

Comment: actually the method `.to_h` is supported from Ruby 2.1.
An alternative way is `Hash[your_array]`

Comment: This worked like a charm! Now to integrate this as a seperate just for my legend. Thanks! And to average the last 4?

Comment: Try to have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341271/how-do-i-create-an-average-from-a-ruby-array)

Comment: You could write `hash.to_a.last(4).to_h` instead of ` hash.map{|h| h}[-4..-1].to_h`.

Answer (score 5):

The following uses [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select) to avoid the need to convert the hash to an array, manipulate the array and then convert it back to a hash.

```
h = { "b"=>1, "d"=>6, "f"=>3, "e"=>1, "c"=>3, "a"=>7 }
```

```
sz = h.size
  #=> 6
h.select { (sz -= 1) < 4 }
  #=> {"f"=>3, "e"=>1, "c"=>3, "a"=>7}
```

Alternatively, if using Ruby 2.5+ one could use [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
h.slice(*h.keys[-4..-1])
  #=> {"f"=>3, "e"=>1, "c"=>3, "a"=>7}
```

and if using Ruby 2.6+ one could employ an [*Endless range*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Range.html):

```
h.slice(*h.keys[-4..])
  #=> {"f"=>3, "e"=>1, "c"=>3, "a"=>7}
```

Comment: I really like `h.slice(*h.keys[-4..-1])` because it's expressive and unambiguous.

Comment: @stevec, thanks! Not only is your change more expressive but it corrects an error I made. I had written `h.slice(*h.keys[2..-1])`, but that needed to be `h.slice(*h.keys[h.size-4..-1])`. Please understand I was just a kid when I wrote that.

Comment: Even better you can do `h.slice(*h.keys.last(4))` if you just want the last 4.

Answer (score 1):

```
metrics.sort.last(4).to_h
```

Will give you a hash with the last four elements.

---

Assuming you didn't originally want to sort, use the same idea:

```
metrics.to_a.last(4).to_h
```

---

**Update:** Given you added the 1.9 restriction and `Array#to_h` comes from 2.1 onward, you can replace `x.to_h` with `Hash[x]`.

Or if you don't need the hash and want to iterate over the key/value pairs, omitting the `.to_h` part and continuing with `.each do |key, value|` will pretty much do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the hash to a 2-element array, select the last for elements and convert back to hash:

```
top_points = {}
(1..10).each { |i| top_points[i] = i*2 }
# => top_points == {1=>2, 2=>4, 3=>6, 4=>8, 5=>10, 6=>12, 7=>14, 8=>16, 9=>18, 10=>20}

Hash[top_points.to_a[-4..-1]]
# => {7=>14, 8=>16, 9=>18, 10=>20}
```

You need to use ruby 1.9+ for this to work (since this version it keeps hash keys in the given order).