# RUBY ON RAILS 4.2.3 Calculate average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm junior RoR programmer.
I know that Ruby language has a calculate method, When I type this in rails console: `ModelName.average(:something)`,it calculates the average value from field `:something`. It works, but how to add average value to the view?

I have a Items catalogue. Every item has a Review which include rating (integer).

How to display on the view (i.e. **show.html.erb**) the average value from all rating fields in Review model?

Comment: Is this a question of passing the value from the controller to the view?

Comment: how to configure controller in that case and how to pass the average value to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVE** STEP BY STEP:

**first step:** Add to your model controller, to def show:
`@rating = Model.where(:model_id => params[:id]).average(:attribute).to_i`

**second step:** add to your model view to show.html.erb:
`<%= @rating %>`

`model_id` = your model, i.e. Post will be `:post_id`
`:attribute` = your attribute, i.e. :rating

It's all.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this. Easiest way is exposing it as a state on the controller, which is the `@average`, which can then be accessed in the view. As easy as it might be, I don't recommend this approach.

What I do recommend is, adding a method on your model, 
`model_instance#review_ average` and when you are exposing (using the `@model_instance`) the instance of the model in the `#show` action of your controller to the view, you can just call `@model_instance.review_average`

What is the advantage of the second approach? It hides the logic from the view and controller, and pushes it into the model, which in turn makes it easier to write an automated test case.

for implementing average, check: [How do I create an average from a Ruby array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341271/how-do-i-create-an-average-from-a-ruby-array)

I'm also guessing that you have a has-many relation. It should not be too difficult to do the above.

One thing that you have to also keep an eye for, is n+1 queries, But this becomes an issue only when you have to show the avg in the index page.

Comment: // def review_avarage @review = Review.average(:rating) end   //    and in show view <%= [at]review.review_avarage %> ???

Comment: usually what I would do is,
`def show
@review = Review.find(:id)
end`

app/views/reviews/show.html.erb

`Average: <%= @review.average%>`

Comment: @FilipMaryniak I think what @bsvin33t is suggesting is to add a method on your Review model and then call that method in the view. In your case, in `app/views/reviews` you define: `def average_rating Review.average(:rating) end` and in `app/views/reviews` you you'll have `<%= @review.average_rating %>`. Also if every item has a review (and assuming you've set your associations properly), you'll be able to access its rating via `@item.review.average_rating` in `app/views/items/show.html.erb`.

Comment: undefined method `average_rating' for nil:NilClass
still

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following to your show.html.erb :

```
<%= @model.average_rating %>
```

Comment: Everything what i do: "undefined method `average_rating' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: have you defined a 'average_rating' method in your model? Also it may have to do with the data type your trying to average (maybe you're dealing with strings?)

in your model, define a method .e.g. 

`def average_rating
    model.average(:rating).to_f
  end`

Comment: That error definitely makes me think you're not defining the method correctly in the model.

Comment: I defined in controller `def @rating = Model.average(:rating) end` and into view i defined `<%= @rating %>`. It works, but it shows me a strange  number. At first, my item hasn't got any ratings but the controller show i.e. 11.404040 (?). At second, i think, that my method calculate all ratings from all items which belongs to Model, not from one. But it is not solving the first problem, because if I have only one item - it shows me a strange number too. Any ideas? Thanks for all responses.

Comment: So, I'm creating the catalogue, every item in the catalogue has reviews with users rating, i want to calculate average rating from reviews for one item.

Comment: def @rating = Model.average(:rating).to_f
Give that a go