# How to calculate averages of items in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, average

I am writing a method that takes an array and returns another array of the averages of each number and the next number in the array.

I tried using `map` but have been staring at it too long and can't see where I'm going wrong:

```
array = [ 1, 3, 5, 1, -10]
array.map! { |a| (a + arr[a+1])/2 }
```

I expect:

```
[ 2, 4, 3, -4.5]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341318/1995757

Comment: if you don't want to use `each_cons` then `(0..(array.size-2)).map {|i| (array[i]+array[i+1]) / 2.0 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
array = [ 1, 3, 5, 1, -10]
array.each_cons(2).map { |a| a.inject(:+) / 2.0 }
#=> [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, -4.5]
```

Summarizing it into a method:

```
def each_cost_avg(array, size = 2)
  array.each_cons(size).map { |a| a.inject(:+) / size.to_f }
end

each_cost_avg(array, 2) #=> [2.0, 4.0, 3.0, -4.5]
each_cost_avg(array, 3) #=> [3.0, 3.0, -1.3333333333333333]
each_cost_avg(array, 4) #=> [2.5, -0.25]
```

Comment: how about `/ 2.0` in the block?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 added `size` variable to make it more dynamic :)

Comment: @ooh yes. I wonder if the OP wants `4.0, 3,0` returned in the array or just `4`, `3` etc? Otherwise, neat answer.

Comment: I can't find the reference, but I think using the block `{ |a,b| (a+b) / 2.0 }` may be faster and IMHO looks nicer too.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 very well might be faster, can't benchmark at the moment (I'm sleeping :D)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** the key takeaway to follow is that you are indexing your array with the an array value, not an index.

There's lots of available one line answers to your question so I'll try to 
address your code:

```
array.map! { |a| (a + arr[a + 1]) / 2 }
```

### Map

The key thing to understand with `map` is that it acts on an array and returns an array (you used `map!` which is in place, but we can disregard that for now. <strike>You can't get the average with map because it returns an array.</strike>

Ex:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map { |num| num * num } # returns [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

So let's walk through your code and see what it is doing:

```
[1, 2, 3].map { |a| (a + arr[a + 1]) / 2 }
```

The first call to `|a| (a + arr[a + 1]) / 2`, `a` will be 1. So the first element of your returned array is `1 + arr[1 + 1] / 2 = 1 + 3 / 2 ~= 2`
And so on. Clearly this isn't what you want.

### Inject/Reduce

Now for the one line solutions (I took this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341318/1995757)):

```
arr.inject { |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
```

`inject` is the same as `reduce`, which is `foldr` in some languages. This is a bit more complicated than `map`. Basically the method `|sum, el| sum + el` is applied to the first two elements, and the result of that is applied to the third element and so on until the end of the array.

So if our array is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, a arithmetic call stack might look something like this:

```
((1 + 2) + 3) + 4
```

With these two methods, you should be able to accomplish what you need, i.e. an array of averages. Or at the very least this should help you understand the other solutions.

Comment: "You can't get the average with map because it returns an array." The OP wants an array. Note : I didn't downvote.

Comment: Yup, I noticed that after. I figure I'll leave this up since it's a good explanation of both why his code doesn't work and how `map` and `reduce` work (I may have jumped right to the commented link on the question and assumed what the question was... my mistake).

Comment: Also : Ruby comments are with `#`, not `//`

Comment: This by no means answers the OP. It should be either corrected to ***answer*** the ***question*** or deleted.

Comment: Well actually it explains why OP's code doesn't work and gives some details on the methods used in the accepted answer. Also, the consensus [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers) is that partial answers are better than no answer. If you link to a somewhere that argues that "It should be either corrected to answer the question or deleted" is the policy than I'll be happy to remove it.