# Function with arrays as a parameter

Tags: ruby, average

How can I write a Ruby function that can calculate the average of an array? If the array doesn't have any elements, the result should be 0. I should use a loop for the implementation. I started like this, but I'm not quite sure how to use the loop.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def average(a)  
  sum = 0.0
  result = 0.0
  if array.length > 0 then
    array.each do |item|
      sum += item
    end
    result = sum / array.length
  end
  return result.to_f
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create an average from a Ruby array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341271/how-do-i-create-an-average-from-a-ruby-array)

Comment: The only difference is you're trying to wrap the average calculation in a method.

Comment: I'm confused... what does that mean 'trying to wrap the average calculation in a method'?

Comment: About your question and the possible duplicate.

Comment: _"I should use a loop"_ – could you be more specific? What qualifies as a loop?

Comment: I can't be more specific thats just what my prof told us to include.

Comment: If you can't be more specific, then we cannot answer your question. How can we tell you what it looks like to "use a loop" if you can't tell us what "use a loop" means? For example, in your code, there is nothing that I would call a "loop". Also, it makes no sense to use a loop for this. The entire code is just `def average(a) return 0 if a.empty?; a.sum.fdiv(a.size) end`.

Comment: I know that's what was confusing me ...

Comment: If your exercise instructions are confusing, the most likely person to help you, is the person who gets paid to make sure your exercise instructions are not confusing, i.e. your TA / instructor / teacher / professor. Random anonymous people on the interwebs cannot really read your instructor's mind, I'm afraid. When I was confronted with exercises like this, I would simply solve them several different ways, e.g. with a library method, a higher-order function, tail-recursion, and a loop, and then discuss the pros and cons of those 4 approaches.

Comment: That makes sense... I was translating the exercise so I'm not quite sure if that's the reason I can't be more specific.

Comment: What is `array`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def average(arr, precision=0)
  return 0 if arr.empty?
  arr.sum.fdiv(arr.size).round(precision)
end

arr = [1,2,3,7]

average(arr)   #=> 3
average(arr,2) #=> 3.25
```

Rather than using [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv) you could write

```
(arr.sum.to_f/arr.size).round(precision)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose we can also write it simply as below

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
def average(arr=[])  
  sum = 0.0
  i=0
  while(i < arr.length) do
    sum += arr[i].to_f
    i += 1
  end
  return ((i==0) ? 0 : (sum / i))
end
```

We can loop and calculate sum this way. Afterwards for average we took value of i which will be retained value after loop and make conditional operator for returning result.

Its simple solution, I have not tested it though so can have mistakes. You can try on your side. Hope This helps !!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Which function does the 'i = 0' have?

Comment: just a measure that 'i' will not be local to the while loop and will be available outside plus it initializes the variable. Did I get your question here?

Comment: Yes I think I get it now. Can you maybe explain why you used '?' in the return-part?

Comment: its a conditional operator ? : which is like if..else..end block in short. It is used to prevent devide-by-zero error if  'i' is 0.  It says if 'i' is 0 then return 0 else divide sum by 'i' to get average which will be float as sum is in decimals.

Comment: If you want more info on the conditional operator (also called ternary operator), this is a good answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4252945/249353

Comment: This is one of the many reasons I dislike the conditional operator. What's wrong with a conditional expression here? `return if i.zero? then 0 else sum / i end` (Actually, in both cases, the `return` is superfluous and non-idiomatic.)

Comment: Note: using the `do` keyword in multi-line loops non-idiomatic. Using parentheses around the condition is non-idiomatic. Using no whitespace around binary operators is non-idiomatic.

Comment: Ok Noted @JörgWMittag. One request can you please update the code above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
def average(values)
    total = 0.0

    values.each do |i| 
        total += i
    end

    return total / values.length()
end
```

If you want to use a loop, you can do it this way:

```
def average(values=[])
    total = 0.0

    for i in values
        total += i
    end

    return total / values.length()
end
```

If a non-empty array is passed, it will return the average of the values. If an empty array is passed, it will return `0.0`.

You can test it like this:

```
puts average([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) #=> "3"
puts average([]) #=> "0"
```

Comment: Did you actually run your code? It produces neither `"3"` nor `"0"`

Comment: @Stefan those are the results it's producing for me.

Comment: Your second example is not more of a loop than the first one. `for` / `in` is simply syntactic sugar for `each` (with slightly different semantics for variable binding), so your two examples are more or less the same. The only actual loop construct Ruby has, is the `while` loop.

Comment: @Davidthethird interesting, I get `3.0` and `NaN`

Comment: @JörgWMittag the OP wanted to use a loop, so I used an example with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def average(a)
  if a.empty?
    0
  else
    sum = a.inject(0.0){|x, sum| sum += x}
    sum / a.size.to_f
  end
end
```